# What is the Max Image Size (File Size or Pixel Size) I can Upload to a Website with iOS Safari?

Tags: ios, image, mobile-safari

I am making a simple picture uploader on my website. (Not an App) During my testing, I noticed that I cannot upload panorama pictures on my iPhone to my website.

I think that my Safari is blocking their uploads due to their file sizes or pixel sizes. (I am resizing panoramas to be under .5 M bytes before sending.) What is the upload size limit of Safari and where should I look for this information? I am reading Safari documentation but have not found yet.

Answer (score 0):

The max limit of file size would be set on back-end.
For example, in CodeIgniter, when do config upload class.
some info such as max size or file type will be set.

So I suggest you to review your backend(file uploading part).

Comment: I am using Django, and its max is bigger than .5 M, so it should not be a problem :(

Comment: Oh, wait, image is not but encoded Request body is?